# Is it possible to authenticate with Azure AD in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have a question. 
I've written a RestAPI with Azure AD authentication. I want to use the API in a dynamic way with Excel VBA. Does anyone knows how to authenticate with Excel VBA?
(If I try with regular Excel new query => other source => web => organizational account, I get an error when I try to sign in : 
WWW-Authenticate header doesn't contain a valid authorization URI)
Anyone a sollution? Thanks in advance!